# How can i auto play the video using jwplayer in ipad the code above

Tags: jwplayer

This code works in a browser, but not in mobile devices.

How can i make it work for mobile devices?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#game_flash').on( "touchstart", function(){
        $(this).remove();
    }); 
    $('#game_flash').trigger('touchstart');

}); 

jwplayer("game_flash").play();
```

Comment: iOS devices remove autostart...

Answer (score 2):

Autoplay is not possible on iOS devices. On iOS, jwplayer uses the HTML 5 video tag, and this has some restrictions on iOS:

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)